# Errno::EISDIR: Is a directory @ rb_sysopen - public

Tags: sass

I'm trying to run this command
sass --watch assets/stylesheets/style.scss:public style.css

it says

> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
>   Errno::EISDIR: Is a directory @ rb_sysopen - public
>     Use --trace for backtrace.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Just spend 1+ hour pulling my hair out over this. I'm working on a Laravel project and importing `bootstrap-sass` via npm. Directory structure:

```
[project root]
|-node_modules
| |-bootstrap-sass
|   |-assets
|     |-stylesheets
|       |-_bootstrap.scss
|-resources
  |-sass
    |-assets
      |-app.scss
```

The problem was that it couldn't find the `node_modules` directory. In `resources/assets/sass/app.scss`, I changed this:

`@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";`

...to this:

`@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";`

It works, but I feel like I've missed something obvious, so would love to see a better solution.